# NestJS, 500 "Internal server error" in authentication

Tags: mysql, authentication, postman, nestjs, typeorm

The code does not generate errors in the terminal when i run it! But when I do the Post Request in postman, the terminal generate this error:

```
{"statusCode":500,"message":"Internal server error"}
```

in my controller, this is the @Post:

```
    @Post('login')
    async login(
        @Body() body: LoginDto,
        @Res({passthrough: true}) response: Response
    ) {
        
        const user = await this.authService.findOneBy(body.email);

        if(!user){
            throw new BadRequestException("Email does not exist");
        }

        if(!await bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.password)){
            throw new BadRequestException("Password does not match");
        }

        const jwt =  await this.jwtService.signAsync({id: user.id});

        response.cookie('jwt', jwt, {httpOnly: true});

        return {
            user
        }
    }
```

This is the file loginDto:

```
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";

export class LoginDto{
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEmail()
    email: string;
    @IsNotEmpty()
    password: string;
}
```

This is the @Injectable Service to find user:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(@InjectRepository(UserEntity) private readonly userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>){   
    }

    async create(user: User): Promise<User>{
        return await this.userRepository.save(user);
    }

    async findOneBy(condition): Promise<User>{
        return await this.userRepository.findOne(condition);
    }

}
```

And This is the entity with TypeORM

```
import { Exclude } from "class-transformer";
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class UserEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    first_name: string;

    @Column()
    last_name: string;

    @Column({unique: true})
    email: string;

    @Column()
    @Exclude()
    password: string;
}
```

I try to find the error whith try and catch:

```
        try{

            if(!user){
                throw new BadRequestException("Email does not exist");
            }

            if(!await bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.password)){
                throw new BadRequestException("Password does not match");
            }

            const jwt =  await this.jwtService.signAsync({id: user.id});

            response.cookie('jwt', jwt, {httpOnly: true});

        } catch (error){

            throw error

        }
```

This is what appears in the terminal:

[Nest] 20445  - 25/11/2022 15:54:19   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] You must provide selection conditions in order to find a single row.
Error: You must provide selection conditions in order to find a single row.
at EntityManager.findOne (/Users/Nicolas/Desktop/NestJS/nest-auth/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts:1094:19)
at Repository.findOne

Comment: At which step is it failing? Which of the functions is it executing? Trace it and let us know please. Wrap it in a try catch and log the error.

Comment: the problem is in your finding in user repository, show that please.

Comment: in the terminal, generate this: [Nest] 19422  - 25/11/2022 14:13:25   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] You must provide selection conditions in order to find a single row.
Error: You must provide selection conditions in order to find a single row.
    at EntityManager.findOne (/Users/Nicolas/Desktop/NestJS/nest-auth/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts:1094:19): I already use try and catch, but remains the same error. I tried with a exception filter of nestjs

Comment: this exception: throw new HttpException({
      status: HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
      error: 'This is a custom message',
    }, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, {
      cause: error

Comment: dude, share this `this.userRepository.findOne(condition)` What is inside that code??

Comment: In the service i have this code:
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(@InjectRepository(UserEntity) private readonly userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>){   
    }

    async create(user: User): Promise<User>{
        return await this.userRepository.save(user);
    }

    async findOneBy(condition): Promise<User>{
        return await this.userRepository.findOne(condition);
    }
}

Comment: I am really new in development. I try to find the repository, and in node_modules, in typeorm, in repository, I find the file "Repository.d.ts: and the metoth is:   findOne(options: FindOneOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity | null>;
    /**
     * Finds first entity that matches given where condition.
     * If entity was not found in the database - returns null.
     */

Comment: It's okay. Go to your repository file, go to your findOne method. And paste the code only for this method inside your question above. Please edit it and paste it like the other code snippets you shared. The code in the comments is not really readable.

Comment: The code for `return await this.userRepository.findOne(condition);`

Comment: I am sorry! I really do not understand! I understand that this method in class AuthService (findOneBy), calls the findOne method in the typeorm repository, but it is automatically! I haven't done any more code. What I found in the repository files is this:
findOne(options: FindOneOptions<Entity>):
Promise<Entity | null>; /** * Finds first entity that matches given where condition. * If entity was not found in the database - returns null. */

Comment: the error is clear, it says you need to pass something unique to the query. That's why I'm asking you to share the code for what is inside the find unique.

Comment: the code is inside typeORM framework, the repository file only give me this code:findOne(options: FindOneOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity | null>; /** * Finds first entity that matches given where condition. * If entity was not found in the database - returns null. */

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the newer versions of Typeorm (3.1), and the last version of NestJS (9.1.4) and I have read that they dropped support for `ormconfig.{json,xml}` files. So you need  to put your database connection options in a `ts` or `js` file using a Data Source and export it.

For me, the solution that work was, downgrade your typeorm to 0.2.45:

```
npm i typeorm@0.2.45;
```

the other solution is: Update your code following the new Typeorm docs.

The solution was given by: Luis Vinicius M.